# Getting the UserAuth from a ServiceStack Session

Tags: session, authentication, servicestack

During a basic or credentials authorization event, is there any place to get a handle on the UserAuth of the user being logged in in OnAuthenticated()?

We've extended the AuthSession object and would like to populate it with more data from the UserAuth (including projecting some custom fields out of the Meta).

I know we can load it ourselves by resolving the AuthRepo out of the authService, but I'm wondering if the current UserAuth is already available somewhere to keep us from spending those cycles needlessly.

Comment: Are you talking about `AuthUserSession.OnAuthenticated` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear.  I'm talking about a custom BasicAuthProvider or CredentialsAuthProvider.OnAuthenticated().

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling the `base.OnAuthenticated()` as the first call within your custom auths OnAuthenticated method then the session parameter will be populated with the UserAuth.

To persist it back though, you're going to need to resolve `IAuthRepository` and call `IAuthRepository.SaveUserAuth(session)`.

Comment: The session it produces only has a subset of the UserAuth data in it, not including the metadata which we're using to store some custom items.  If the full UserAuth isn't available, we'll have to pull it back using a resolved AuthRepo.